# Ошибка "expected primary-expression before = token"

Tags: c

Простейшая программа на языке Си, но компилятор выдает такую вот ошибку

> `expected primary-expression before = token`

Среда devcpp. Что не так в коде? Сам код программы:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define PI=3.14
int main()
{
    double k, m, x, z;
    printf("Vvedite x=");
    scanf("%f", &x);
    printf("Vvedite m=");
    scanf("%f", &m);
    z = (exp(PI * x) - exp(-PI * x)) / (pow(10, 3) + sqrt(log(m * x)));
    k = (tan(z) * tan(z)) + ((1 / tan(z)) * (1 / tan(z)));
    printf("t");
    printf("z=%lfnt", z);
    printf("k=%lf", k);
    getchar();
    getchar();
}
```

Не кидайтесь помидорами, ибо я только начинающий.

Comment: Считайте это не помидором. 

Компилятор обычно пишет в какой строке программы ошибка. Хорошим тоном будет отметить в своем вопросе эту строку комментарием (не считать же нам строки (?), даже если бы Вы написали ее номер).

Например

    //******** ОШИБКА 1 ********
    #define PI=3.14
    //**************************

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Попробуйте убрать знак "=" вот как

```
#define PI 3.14
```

Answer (score 2):

Макроопределение неправильно написали: знак "=" не нужен.

```
#define PI 3.14
```